# Equations related to the first-order derivative of the wavefunction

Tags: density-functional-theory, dfpt

I have two brakets (the angular momentum matrix elements) that are
$$ \langle \partial_\mathbf{k} \psi_{n \mathbf{k}} |  \times \mathbf{p} | \psi_{m \mathbf{k}} \rangle \tag{1} $$
$$ \langle \psi_{n \mathbf{k}} |  \mathbf{p} \times  | \partial_\mathbf{k}  \psi_{m \mathbf{k}} \rangle \tag{2} $$
where $\psi_{n \mathbf{k}}$ is Bloch wave function with band index $n$ and wave vector $\mathbf{k}$. $\mathbf{p}$ is the momentum operator and $\partial_\mathbf{k} = {\partial}/{\partial_\mathbf{k}}$. Using the Hermitian conjugate relation $\partial^{\dagger}=-\partial$ and $\partial_{\mathbf{k}} \times \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{0}$, I obtained
$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{Eq.}~(1)&=-\langle \psi_{n \mathbf{k}} | \partial_\mathbf{k} \left [ \times \mathbf{p} | \psi_{m \mathbf{k}} \rangle \right ] \tag{3} \\
&=-\left [ \langle \psi_{n \mathbf{k}} | (\partial_\mathbf{k}  \times \mathbf{p} )| \psi_{m \mathbf{k}} \rangle -\langle \psi_{n \mathbf{k}} |  \mathbf{p} \times  | \partial_\mathbf{k}  \psi_{m \mathbf{k}} \rangle \right ] \tag{4} = \textrm{Eq.}~(2)
\end{align}
$$
Or I can simply use $\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p} = - \mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{r}$ to prove (1)=(2).  However, in my implementations, with $\partial_{\mathbf{k}} \psi_{n \mathbf{k}}$ replaced by the covariant derivative $\mathcal{Q} \partial_{\mathbf{k}} \psi_{n \mathbf{k}}$  where $\mathcal{Q}$ is the projection operator on the empty states$, I found (1) and (2) are not always equal but at some k points and band pairs. **Am I missing something?**

Comment: Not equal, or not complex conjugates of each other?

Comment: Can you clarify by answering the question in @SusiLehtola's comment?

Comment: @SusiLehtola Not equal.

Comment: But it's obvious that they're not equal, since they should be complex conjugates.

Comment: Why complex conjugate? Anything wrong with Eqs (3) and (4)?

Comment: @XiaomingWang equations (1) and (2) are complex conjugates of each other

Comment: Just to clarify @SusiLehtola 's comments, although r is a real operator (in real-space), p is a complex operator and so you need to use the appropriate general definitions of the operations. 

Consider the equivalent dot-product statement: "p.q = q.p" -- this is commonly used in school maths, but is only true if p and q are real;  the more general statement is "p.q = conjg(q.p)", which holds for complex p and q (and reduces to the first statement if p and q are real).

Comment: The matrix element is a scalar (it's just a number), so the complex conjugate is the same as the Hermitian conjugate. p is an observable, so it is hermitian. If you take the Hermitian conjugate of equation 1, according to elementary quantum mechanics you get equation 2. So they are complex conjugates of each other.

Comment: Xiaoming Wang, this conversation ended with two comments by @SusiLehtola and one by $PhilHasnip, and no response from you to any of the last three comments. Are you still interested in the problem? Were those comments helpful? We'd like to clear up the unanswered queue (especially for questions that were asked almost a year ago) so if you now know the answer, please write a self-answer, and otherwise perhaps reply to the last comments, so that maybe one of them can answer, or if you're not interested anymore we can also close the question!

Comment: This questions seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone would like to provide an answer or the OP addresses suggestions made in the comments.